# Player in game stopped playing

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I'm working on a game in iOS, which needs an internet connection. The problem I'm having is setting a Bool on the server (parse.com) when the player stops playing. Right now I'm doing this...

```
-(void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    NSLog(@"Player logged out");
    [self playerLoggedOut];
}
```

and

```
-(void)playerLoggedOut
{
    PFUser *currentUser = [PFUser currentUser];

    if (currentUser) {

        [currentUser setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:@"playing"];

        [currentUser saveEventually];
        [sharedInstance requestSentWithDesc:@"Player logged out"];
    }
}
```

But that doesn't seem to be working, there's also the situation of the game crashing, when I believe the above would never get called.

There's also...

```
-(void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
```

But I'm not sure when's that called.

There is the possibility of using a timer, but if the player never logs back in, or doesn't for a long time I'm not sure how a timer could be used.

Answer (score 0):

For your current processing you would need to start a background task (see [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html)) which starts before you make the request and ends in the completion block (so change the save method you use).

For the other cases this won't work and you may want to add some kind of 'keep-alive' message an / or parse cloud code which monitors the user interaction and automatically logs them out if they are inactive for a set time.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid cloud code if at all possible as that adds another layer of complexity to everything. What I don't get is that I'm using TestFlight and somehow that SDK always knows when the game has crashed or ended, so there must be a way of doing it within the app, or is TestFlight using that background task you mentioned?

Comment: It will be using a combination of background task and I handled exception handler I guess.

Answer (score 0):

If your game is crashing, you must get any logs, for example:
[image]
Or something else. You can add `NSLog(@"worked to the bitter end!");` at the end of your `-(void)playerLoggedOut` or `requestSentWithDesc` method.

Comment: `applicationWillTerminate` is not called when the app crashes. It's basically never called since apps go to the background.

Comment: I'm using TestFlight to record crashes.